# PHP check boxes as boolean values

Tags: php, checkbox

I need to create a Preferences table in a SQL using data from checkboxes. That is Pool,Jacuzzi, Backyard, Smart House are columns in Preferences that are TINYINTS to represent Boolean T or F. When a user checks a box, I want the value to be 1, else it stays at 0. So say a user wants a Pool and a Backyard and checks those two boxes. my $_POST[preferences] would be an array that would be [1,0,1,0].

```
<input type="checkbox" name="preferences[]" value="Pool"> Pool<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="preferences[]" value="Jacuzzi"> Jacuzzi<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="preferences[]" value="Backyard"> Backyard<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="preferences[]" value="Smart"> Smart House<br>
```

UPDATE:
Ok yes this is close. This is what I have which is somewhat similar to this, however I can't tell if it is actually giving a value of 1 or 0. If it's 1, it shows up in the array but if it's not checked it doesn't. So it ends up being [Pool,Jacuzzi]. I am not sure though if they have the value of 1 and the other ones have a value of 0, or is it just implied.

```
foreach ($preferences as $key => $val) {
if(isset($key)){
$val=1;
}
else{
$val = 0;
}
}
```

UPDATE2: Solution I found to work kind of similar to @chris85

```
 ** I found out that keeping hidden checkboxes would work for defaulting values to zero if they arent checked.

 <input type="hidden" name="pool" value="0"/>
 <input type="checkbox" id="pool" name="pool" value="1">Pool<br>

 $low= $_POST['low'];
 $high =$_POST['high'];
 $pool = $_POST['pool'];
 $jacuzzi= $_POST['jacuzzi'];
 $backyard= $_POST['backyard'];
 $smart= $_POST['smart'];
 $addPreferences = "INSERT INTO Preferences(Pool,Jacuzzi,Backyard,Smart)
 VALUES ('$pool','$jacuzzi','$backyard','$smart')";
```

Comment: Have you tried the answer I provided? Or can you explain why you need an array as described?

Comment: What's the status here, no luck, works perfectly, kinda works?

Comment: Have you tried var_dump($preferences) on the page you are posting to to see what is being posted and what is contained in your array.

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this to to assign values to each preference.

```
$magic['pool'] = 0;
$magic['smart'] = 0;
$magic['jacuzzi'] = 0;
$magic['backyard'] = 0;
if(!empty($preferences)){
    foreach($preferences as $preference) {
        $magic[$preference] = 1;
    }
}
print_r($magic);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [pool] => 0
    [smart] => 0
    [jacuzzi] => 0
    [backyard] => 0
)
```

Comment: Ok yes this is close. This is what I have which is somewhat similar to this, however I can't tell if it is actually giving a value of 1 or 0. If it's 1, it shows up in the array but if it's not checked it doesn't. foreach ($preferences as $key => $val) {
    if(isset($key)){
    $val=1;
}
else{
$val = 0;
}
}

Comment: It won't transmit if it isn't checked thats why I set the default values. Then if it is transmitted it will be '1'.

Comment: If this resolves your issue please be sure to accept the answer. If there is something else needed please update.

Comment: It didn't actually. I just need the check boxes to give me an string of form(0,1,1,0). This would be the same as checking the jacuzzi and backyard box, but leaving the other two unchecked.

Comment: Oh, had a typo in my initial answer, should have been `$$` not `$$$`. I've updated with the variables set to an array, not clear why you can't use the variables but this should work.

Comment: @derp so what is the status here?

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

```
$val = count($_POST['preferences']) ? 1 : 0;
```

Comment: How will OP know if `Pool` or `Smart` was checked with this code?

Comment: Maybe I can be clearer. If a user checks a box, i want the value to be 1 or 0 if unchecked. So an array essentially would be made like this [1,0,0,1] where array[index] corresponds with a value such a pool,jacuzzi,smart house,backyard.

Comment: so you want to get values for each checkbox??

Comment: `count` would not be a good choice here in any event, an e_notice will be thrown if non of the items are selected; the count also is useless so you might as well just use `empty` or `isset`. @derp You should update your question with a bit more information, such as how is this data being used later.

Comment: Yes. When a user checks a box I want the value of "Pool" to be 1, or stay 0 otherwise.

Comment: are the values fixed?? for checkbox??

Comment: @chris85 I updated the question so it may be clearer. But I am looking into isset right now.