# PHP syntax error on Update

Tags: php, mysql

Hey guys I keep getting an error on my Update form and it's driving me nuts. I can't figure out where it's at? Any help would be appreciated.

```
<?php
include 'connect.php';
?>
<form action = 'updateclient.php' method= 'post'>

Select an ID: <input type="text" name="id"><br>
Update Name: <input type="text" name="name"><br>
Update Phone: <input type= "text" name ="phone"><br>
Update Email: <input typer = "text" name="email"><br>

<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
<?php

$sql = "UPDATE Client SET name ='".$_POST['name']."',phone='".$_POST['phone']."',email ='".$_POST['email']."'" ;
$sql.= "WHERE ID = '"$_POST['id']"'";

$result = @mysqli_query($connect,$sql);
?>
```

Comment: Don't use the `@` and ask a question. Check for errors. This code is wide open for a SQL injection..

Comment: Please post the error shown. As @chris85 mentioned, your codes are problematic and lack of error debugging / catching mechanism.

Comment: Also what happened to this question, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33985573/php-check-boxes-as-boolean-values you stopped replying...

Comment: @chris85 I did respond on my UPDATE2. I used hidden boxes to act as a proxy value of 0. It's there sir.

Comment: On update 2 you said `Ahhhhh gotcha. I see. Yes this works.` soo the answer works but you don't accept? You followed up later and asked an additional question I followed up on that twice with no response from you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$sql.= "WHERE ID = '"$_POST['id']"'";
```

should be

```
$sql.= "WHERE ID = '" . $_POST['id'] . "'";
```

This is completely insecure, as others have said. Read up on SQL injection.

Comment: Thanks guys. This is a small project for a database 101 course so I'm aware of injecting and I am storing image BLOBs as well, so not 100% security but thank you for pointing out vulnerabilities when I get more time I will get take a look around the PHP site for help securing data and such.

Answer (score 0):

You really should include the the text of error message. Helps us help you.

But let me take a wild guess.  Print out the `$sql` variable.  I think you will find there is no space character before `WHERE` which might cause parsing of your SQL statement to fail.  Add a space before `WHERE` and it might work.

Note that @chris85 is 1000% right, this code is insecure, subject to SQL injection that could kill your database.